# Robocopy Summary Times not correct

Tags: robocopy

I've set up a robocopy script and it functions correctly.

However, within the summary in the log file, the Total Times does not make sense to me as the job runs for about 109 minutes, but total returns 3:39:06?

Can someone explain why this looks wrong.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : 03 April 2019 20:30:04
   Source : G:\Backup\
     Dest : \\newserver\Backup\

    Files : refresh*

  Options : /V /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /Z /PF /MT:1 /R:5 /W:5 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        New File          21.0 g    G:\Backup\refresh.bak 

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         1         0         0         0         0
   Files :         1         1         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :  21.019 g  21.019 g         0         0         0         0
   Times :   3:39:06   0:54:46                       0:00:00   0:54:46
   Ended : 03 April 2019 22:19:37
```

Comment: Would have been great to have a response for this...

Comment: I should be a bug related to `/MT:1`. The real "Total" time is "Copied" time + "Extras" time. MS should make Robocopy open source, I think.

Comment: The total time is broken as soon as you use the `/MT` option not just `/MT:1`.